# How do I update the "board" variable's array's so that the turns of X and O alternate in turns? Btw, this is a Tic Tac Toe Game

Tags: javascript, html, css, tic-tac-toe, web-development-server

```js
let board = [
    ["", "", ""],
    ["", "", ""],
    ["", "", ""]
]


var square1 = document.getElementById("square1")
square1.addEventListener("click", function(turnMove){
    if (turnMove % 2 === 0) {
        square1.innerHTML = "X"
        board[0].splice(0, 0, "X")
    } else {
        square1.innerHTML = "O"
        board[0].splice(0, 0, "O")
    }
    console.log(board)
})

var square2 = document.getElementById("square2")
square2.addEventListener("click", function(turnMove){
    if (turnMove % 2 === 0) {
        square2.innerHTML = "X"
        board[0].splice(1, 1, "X")
    } else {
        square2.innerHTML = "O"
        board[0].splice(1, 1, "O")
    }
    console.log(board)
})

var square3 = document.getElementById("square3")
square3.addEventListener("click", function(turnMove){
    if (turnMove % 2 === 0) {
        square3.innerHTML = "X"
        board[0].splice(2, 2, "X")
    } else {
        square3.innerHTML = "O"
        board[0].splice(2, 2, "O")
    }
    console.log(board)
})

var square4 = document.getElementById("square4")
square4.addEventListener("click", function(turnMove){
    if (turnMove % 2 === 0) {
        square4.innerHTML = "X"
        board[1].splice(0, 0, "X")
    } else {
        square4.innerHTML = "O"
        board[1].splice(0, 0, "O")
    }
    console.log(board)
})

var square5 = document.getElementById("square5")
square5.addEventListener("click", function(turnMove){
    if ((turnMove % 2 === 0)) {
        square5.innerHTML = "X"
        board[1].splice(1, 1, "X")
    } else {
        square5.innerHTML = "O"
        board[1].splice(1, 1, "O")
    }
    console.log(board)
})

var square6 = document.getElementById("square6")
square6.addEventListener("click", function(turnMove){
    if ((turnMove % 2 === 0)) {
        square6.innerHTML = "X"
        board[1].splice(2, 2, "X")
    } else {
        square6.innerHTML = "O"
        board[1].splice(2, 2, "O")
    }
    console.log(board)
})

var square7 = document.getElementById("square7")
square7.addEventListener("click", function(turnMove){
    if ((turnMove % 2 === 0)) {
        square7.innerHTML = "X"
        board[2].splice(0, 0, "X")
    } else {
        square7.innerHTML = "O"
        board[2].splice(0, 0, "O")
    }
    console.log(board)
})

var square8 = document.getElementById("square8")
square8.addEventListener("click", function(turnMove){
    if ((turnMove % 2 === 0)) {
        square8.innerHTML = "X"
        board[2].splice(1, 1, "X")
    } else {
        square8.innerHTML = "O"
        board[2].splice(1, 1, "O")
    }
    console.log(board)
})

var square9 = document.getElementById("square9")
square9.addEventListener("click", function(turnMove){
    if ((turnMove % 2 === 0)) {
        square9.innerHTML = "X"
        board[2].splice(2, 2, "X")
    } else {
        square9.innerHTML = "O"
        board[2].splice(2, 2, "O")
    }
    console.log(board)
})



function turnMove(board) {
    turns = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            if (board[i][j]) {
                turns = turns + 1
            } else {
                turns = turns + 0
            }
        }
    }
    return turns
}
```

```css
#board {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr  1fr;
    max-width: 40%;
    height: 40vw;
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
  
}

.square {
    background-color: aliceblue;
    border: 1px solid black;
    
}

* {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tic Tac Toe Game</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width initial-scale=1">
    </head>

<body>
    <div id="board">
        <div id="square1" class="square"></div>
        <div id="square2" class="square"></div>
        <div id="square3" class="square"></div>
        
        <div id="square4" class="square"></div>
        <div id="square5" class="square"></div>
        <div id="square6" class="square"></div>
        
        <div id="square7" class="square"></div>
        <div id="square8" class="square"></div>
        <div id="square9" class="square"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The function turnMove is determining what move it is in and using this allows the addEventListener to determine if the innerHTML and splice will add "X" or "O" to the div and board arrays.

How can I alternate the "X"s and "O"s? I need to update the board "state." How do I do that?

```js
let board = [
    ["", "", ""],
    ["", "", ""],
    ["", "", ""]
]


var square1 = document.getElementById("square1")
square1.addEventListener("click", function(turnMove){
    if (turnMove % 2 === 0) {
        square1.innerHTML = "X"
        board[0].splice(0, 0, "X")
    } else {
        square1.innerHTML = "O"
        board[0].splice(0, 0, "O")
    }
    console.log(board)
})

// This code is applicable for the 9 squares.
// square2, square2, and so on...

function turnMove(board) {
    turns = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            if (board[i][j]) {
                turns = turns + 1
            } else {
                turns = turns + 0
            }
        }
    }
    return turns
}
```

Comment: You have a function `turnMove(board)` that takes a parameter, but the parameter is never given and the function is not even invoked(). `turnMove` is just the function object and `turnMove % 2' will never be true. `turns = turns + 0` also does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my way to fix your problem.

#### 1. Edit your `turnMove()`

You want to increase the turns every time a square is clicked on. It could be very simple, like this:

```js
let turns = 0;
const turnMove = () => turns++;
```

#### 2. Change the way you use `turnMove()`

You need to call turnMove as a function which is `turnMove()`, not `turnMove`. And `yourSquareElement` is a parameter from the on-click callback, you can change its name to whatever you want, but you can't change its value.

```js
square9.addEventListener("click", function(yourSquareElement){
    if((turnMove() % 2 === 0)){}
})
```

Those are two things to solve your problem. One tip for you is to put variables in `console.log()` to see what value they're holding. If you do that, you will see `yourSquareElement` is actually an Event object no matter what name you give it.

See my demo here:

```js
let board = [
    ["", "", ""],
    ["", "", ""],
    ["", "", ""]
]


var square1 = document.getElementById("square1")
square1.addEventListener("click", function(el){
    if(turnMove() % 2 === 0){
        square1.innerHTML = "X"
        board[0].splice(0, 0, "X")
    }else{
        square1.innerHTML = "O"
        board[0].splice(0, 0, "O")
    }
    console.log(board)
})

var square2 = document.getElementById("square2")
square2.addEventListener("click", function(el){
    if(turnMove() % 2 === 0){
        square2.innerHTML = "X"
        board[0].splice(1, 1, "X")
    }else{
        square2.innerHTML = "O"
        board[0].splice(1, 1, "O")
    }
    console.log(board)
})

var square3 = document.getElementById("square3")
square3.addEventListener("click", function(el){
    if(turnMove() % 2 === 0){
        square3.innerHTML = "X"
        board[0].splice(2, 2, "X")
    }else{
        square3.innerHTML = "O"
        board[0].splice(2, 2, "O")
    }
    console.log(board)
})

var square4 = document.getElementById("square4")
square4.addEventListener("click", function(el){
    if(turnMove() % 2 === 0){
        square4.innerHTML = "X"
        board[1].splice(0, 0, "X")
    }else{
        square4.innerHTML = "O"
        board[1].splice(0, 0, "O")
    }
    console.log(board)
})

var square5 = document.getElementById("square5")
square5.addEventListener("click", function(el){
    if((turnMove() % 2 === 0)){
        square5.innerHTML = "X"
        board[1].splice(1, 1, "X")
    }else{
        square5.innerHTML = "O"
        board[1].splice(1, 1, "O")
    }
    console.log(board)
})

var square6 = document.getElementById("square6")
square6.addEventListener("click", function(el){
    if((turnMove() % 2 === 0)){
        square6.innerHTML = "X"
        board[1].splice(2, 2, "X")
    }else{
        square6.innerHTML = "O"
        board[1].splice(2, 2, "O")
    }
    console.log(board)
})

var square7 = document.getElementById("square7")
square7.addEventListener("click", function(el){
    if((turnMove() % 2 === 0)){
        square7.innerHTML = "X"
        board[2].splice(0, 0, "X")
    }else{
        square7.innerHTML = "O"
        board[2].splice(0, 0, "O")
    }
    console.log(board)
})

var square8 = document.getElementById("square8")
square8.addEventListener("click", function(el){
    if((turnMove() % 2 === 0)){
        square8.innerHTML = "X"
        board[2].splice(1, 1, "X")
    }else{
        square8.innerHTML = "O"
        board[2].splice(1, 1, "O")
    }
    console.log(board)
})

var square9 = document.getElementById("square9")
square9.addEventListener("click", function(el){
    if((turnMove() % 2 === 0)){
        square9.innerHTML = "X"
        board[2].splice(2, 2, "X")
    }else{
        square9.innerHTML = "O"
        board[2].splice(2, 2, "O")
    }
    console.log(board)
})

let turns = 0;
const turnMove = () => turns++;
```

```css
#board {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr  1fr;
    max-width: 40%;
    height: 40vw;
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
  
}

.square {
    background-color: aliceblue;
    border: 1px solid black;
    
}

* {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tic Tac Toe Game</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width initial-scale=1">
    </head>

<body>
    <div id="board">
        <div id="square1" class="square"></div>
        <div id="square2" class="square"></div>
        <div id="square3" class="square"></div>
        
        <div id="square4" class="square"></div>
        <div id="square5" class="square"></div>
        <div id="square6" class="square"></div>
        
        <div id="square7" class="square"></div>
        <div id="square8" class="square"></div>
        <div id="square9" class="square"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Update: I refactored your script to make it even cleaner.

I merged all the on-click events for each square into one, hope you find this useful. Your script now is:

```js
const board = [
    ["", "", ""],
    ["", "", ""],
    ["", "", ""]
];


let turns = 0;
const turnMove = () => turns++;
const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');

squares.forEach((thisSquare, index) => {
    const col = index % 3;
    const row = Math.floor(index / 3);

    thisSquare.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const player = turnMove() % 2 === 0 ? "X" : "O";

        thisSquare.innerHTML = player;
        board[row][col] = player;

        console.log(row, col, board);
    });
});
```

```js
const board = [
  ["", "", ""],
  ["", "", ""],
  ["", "", ""]
];


let turns = 0;
const turnMove = () => turns++;
const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');

squares.forEach((thisSquare, index) => {
  const col = index % 3;
  const row = Math.floor(index / 3);

  thisSquare.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const player = turnMove() % 2 === 0 ? "X" : "O";

    thisSquare.innerHTML = player;
    board[row][col] = player;

    console.log(row, col, board);
  });
});
```

```css
#board {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  max-width: 40%;
  height: 40vw;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.square {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

* {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Tic Tac Toe Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="board">
    <div id="square1" class="square"></div>
    <div id="square2" class="square"></div>
    <div id="square3" class="square"></div>

    <div id="square4" class="square"></div>
    <div id="square5" class="square"></div>
    <div id="square6" class="square"></div>

    <div id="square7" class="square"></div>
    <div id="square8" class="square"></div>
    <div id="square9" class="square"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I updated my answer with a clean code version. And yes, you also need to check for a winner which is provided by `@savageGoat`'s answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. You have given me more than what I have asked for though I would have liked to do the project on my own since still a novice. Thank you again! You are the true winner.

Comment: Is there a way to follow you @phucbm?

Comment: You can reach out to me on some social networks listed on my GitHub profile https://github.com/phucbm

Answer (score 0):

Posting this here as a end result, **this is not a solution** to your problem.

**@phucbm** on the other hand explained what's wrong with your code, that's your solution, this is just a guide for your end result

Use this as a guide, use `@phucbm`'s answer to fix your problem

-

```js
const emptyBoard = [
    ["-", "-", "-"],
    ["-", "-", "-"],
    ["-", "-", "-"]
];
// Break reference by stringify/parsing
let board = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(emptyBoard));
const boardEl = document.querySelector('#board');

const createBoard = () => {
  boardEl.innerHTML = ''; // Reset board on win
  board.map((row, rowIndex) => {
      let rowHTML = ``;
      row.map((col, colIndex) => {
          rowHTML += `<div class="cell" data-row="${rowIndex}" data-col="${colIndex}"></div>`;
      });
      boardEl.innerHTML += `<div class="row">${ rowHTML }</div>`;
  });
}

createBoard(); // Init

const checkForWins = (row, col) => {
    // Check either diagonal or current row / col clicked
    const diagonalLeft = [ board[0][0], board[1][1], board[2][2] ];
    const diagonalRight = [ board[0][2], board[1][1], board[2][0] ];
    const currentRow = [board[row][0], board[row][1], board[row][2]];
    const currentCol = [board[0][col], board[1][col], board[2][col]];

    [ diagonalLeft, diagonalRight, currentRow, currentCol ].map((arr) => {
        const string = arr.join('');

        if (string === 'xxx' || string === 'ooo') {
            alert(string[0]+' wins!');
            board = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(emptyBoard));
            createBoard();
        }
    })
};


let currentPlayer = "x";
boardEl.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
    const row = evt.target.getAttribute('data-row');
    const col = evt.target.getAttribute('data-col');
    const isEmpty = evt.target.innerText === '';

    if (row && col && isEmpty) {
        board[ row ][ col ] = currentPlayer;
        evt.target.innerHTML = board[row][col];
        checkForWins(row, col);
        currentPlayer = currentPlayer === 'x' ? 'o' : 'x';
    }
})
```

```css
#board {
    display: block;
}
#board .row { display: block; font-size: 0; }
#board .row .cell {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 15px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I will use it as a guide for checking wins. Thank you again. I am kinda new to coding so please bear with me.

Comment: Is there a way to follow you @savageGoat?

Comment: No really (yet, but I'll think about it). The cool thing here is that you have a huge community that can bring you way more than just coding, it brings multiple ways to do one thing and pick what you think is best for you. Now I know it's huge and could be intersting to channel this through one person but as stated, the point is not to do what works, the point is to find a way that works for you, and that can only be brought to life by understanding what you want to do, and ask multiple people how to do it, that's what SO is for